# How to Change directory to the python script directory

Tags: python

In batch there is a command `%~dp0` which mean change the directory to the script directory, for example: Batch file is in desktop, if you use `%~dp0` the directory instantly go to the **C:\Users\Windows\Desktop** without you typing it. Is there any code that do the same as `%~dp0` in Python??

Comment: Not 100% sure if it's the thing you are looking for but `print(__file__)` might be the thing you are looking for?

Answer (score 5):

You can implement it through two functions in the `os` and `os.path` modules. `os.chdir` changes the current working directory and `os.path.dirname` returns the directory name from a file path. `__file__` contains the path of the currently running script.

```
import os

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
print(os.getcwd())
```

.. will output the directory where your script is located.